# Leaflet map onload event?

Tags: angularjs

Can any body tell me the onload event for leaflet map. I want to load states from json and by using featureselected() function I want to apply styles on leaflet map.

I am succesfully in getting the map lick event

map.on('click',callbackFunction);

but I want to load all states on page load.

Comment: Have you tried: "load - Fired when the map is initialized (when its center and zoom are set for the first time)."?

Answer (score 5):

You shoud use method 'whenReady()' instead of .on('load',...)

[Leaflet API method whenReady()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-misc-methods)